# Is rename column more effecient on inner select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is rename column let me get more efficient and avoid conflict or no different between the following **SQL** statements:

*keep in your mind i have the same name of fields used on outer select and inner select*.

**A**- With rename column on inner select:

```
delete from aspnet_UsersInRoles
 where
  UserId=(select u.UserId from aspnet_Users u where  u.UserName='Me')
  and 
  RoleId in (select r.RoleId from aspnet_Roles r where r.RoleName in(select name from DSC_Role where isCustomer=0) )
```

**B**- Without rename column on inner select:

```
delete from aspnet_UsersInRoles
 where
  UserId=(select UserId from aspnet_Users where UserName='Me')
  and 
  RoleId in (select RoleId from aspnet_Roles where RoleName in(select name from DSC_Role where isCustomer=0) )
```

Which one is the best?

Comment: Please clarify which is the referred SQL engin (mysql, SQL Server or Oracle)

Comment: You haven't renamed a column; you've aliased a table. There is no difference in meaning or performance. (To prove this to yourself, compare the query plans of the statements.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no difference between the query plans for bith versions of your query. You should not expect one to be more efficient or faster than the other.

Aliasing the tables should only help with disambiguation and making your queries easier to read. It should not affect the actual execution plans in the underlying DBMS.

Comment: what did you mean by disambiguation  (conflict on result or conflict on reading ) ?

Comment: Say you have a query like `SELECT name FROM person INNER JOIN person ON (parent_id = id)`. In this example name, parent_id and id are all ambiguous since it is unclear which person table they refer to. The common way to work around this is to use table aliases, for example: `SELECT p1.name FROM person p1 INNER JOIN person p2 ON (p1.parent_id = p2.id)`. Other times when you have several tables that share the same column names, you will have to disambiguate using the table names before the column names, aliases can help you make those queries more compact and hopefully more readable.

Comment: thanks Sebstian , i am talking about my example do you think i need to rename columns to avoid ambiguation ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It depends on the columns each table has, but if the DBMS is not raising errors then it is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not **renaming** the columns, you are using a **table alias** while referring the columns in the **SELECT** list.

There is no difference in terms of performance. Compare the explain plans(below demo is for **Oracle**):

**With table alias**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT empno FROM emp;

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

8 rows selected.
```

**Without table alias**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT e.empno FROM emp e;

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

8 rows selected.
```

You could also compare the **statistics** using `set autot on` in **SQL*Plus**:

**With alias**

```
Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          8  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         10  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        702  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        544  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         14  rows processed
```

**Without alias**

```
Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          8  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         10  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        702  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        544  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         14  rows processed
```

No difference at all.